# Hibernate search: configured sub-types

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have three entities, where the BEntity and CEntity extends from AEntity

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public class AEntity {
    @Id
    private String externalId;
}

@Entity
@Indexed
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
public class BEntity extends AEntity {
    @Field
    private String number;
}

@Entity
@Indexed
@DiscriminatorValue("C")
public class CEntity extends AEntity {
    @Field
    private String number;
}
```

now i want to search in the sub entities where number equals 1234, i tried with the below but i have this error

> HSEARCH000331: Can't build query for type 'BEntity' which is neither
> configured nor has any configured sub-types.

```
public void unicity() {
    List<Query> listOfQuery = new ArrayList<>();
   // error in this line
    QueryBuilder queryBuilder1 = getFullTextEntityManager().getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(BEntity.class).get();
    QueryBuilder queryBuilder2 = getFullTextEntityManager().getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(CEntity.class).get();
    listOfQuery.add(queryBuilder1.keyword().onField("number").matching("1234").createQuery());
    listOfQuery.add(queryBuilder2.keyword().onField("number").matching("1234").createQuery());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the `@Indexed` annotation is really `org.hibernate.search.annotations.Indexed`, not some other annotation from another library.
2. Make sure `BEntity` is actually detected as an entity. Are you able to run queries targeting this type with Hibernate ORM? E.g. using JPQL or Criteria?
3. Make sure you didn't disable Hibernate Search, i.e. that you didn't set `hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners` to `false`.